# Armazenar caminhos que contém diretório com espaço no nome

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script

Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema: Preciso que no meu script armazene um caminho de um diretório X em uma variável. O grande problema é que uma das pastas neste caminho contém espaço no nome e por algum motivo ao chamar a variável dá um conflito no diretório com espaço. Ex:

Se eu usar assim funciona:

```
cd "/home/douglas/Minha Pasta"
```

Mas se for assim não funciona:

```
home="/home/douglas/Minha Pasta"
cd $home
```

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma outra opção é referenciar a variável entre aspas duplas:

```
home="/home/douglas/Minha Pasta"
cd "$home"
```

Segundo a [documentação, *5.1*. Quoting Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html):

> <sub>(Em tradução livre)</sub>
>
> Ao fazer referência a uma variável, é geralmente aconselhável incluir seu nome entre aspas duplas.
>
> Isso impede a reinterpretação de todos os caracteres especiais
>   dentro da cadeia entre aspas - exceto `$`, `` ` ``(acento grave), e `\`
>   (escape). [...]
>
> Use aspas duplas para evitar separação de palavras. Um argumento
>   entre aspas apresenta-se como uma única palavra, mesmo que contenha
>   separadores de espaço em branco.

Comment: Não funciona :(

Comment: @Douglas Em teoria era para funcionar, veja [esse demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMeEZLY1RScGZJdHc), clique em "Execute" e veja a saída do `cd`. Qual erro é exibida na tua máquina?

Comment: Obrigado, eu não havia observado que a variável ficava entre "". Agora funcionou, show.

Comment: Usando uma variável: root_app=$PWD consigo armazenar o diretório atual, mas não consigo entrar na pasta com espaços via script assim: cd "$root_app" 

O pwd não cria as \ nos espaços, como faço para entrar na pasta?

Answer (score 6):

Você vai precisar escapar os espaços para que o comando funcione, quando você usa o comando `cd $home` é o mesmo que: `/home/douglas/Minha Pasta`, ele vai ler até o *Minha* e não vai encontrar a pasta;

Faça `home="/home/douglas/Minha\ Pasta"`, com o `\` antes do espaço.

Comment: Jà fiz isso tudo e não funciona :(

Comment: Qual mensagem aparece?

Comment: Resolvi, obrigado :)